# Get authorization from remote API

Tags: keycloak

I’m using Keycloak (OIDC) for authentication, and I want to add permissions of users to their access token.

My problem is that our permissions are managed by a dedicated application, and that we can recover them by an API.

So : How can I add authorizations to the claims of an access token, by getting these authorizations from a remote API?

Comment: Configure mapper for your OIDC client.

Comment: Just configuration? I can see that I'm able to add simple fields with mappers, but I can't find a way of getting remote data...

Comment: Sure, you can code your own mapper. Random example https://github.com/mschwartau/keycloak-custom-protocol-mapper-example